# Android soft keyboard - get the exact length of the animation?

Tags: java, android

Nowadays we can finally easily know when the Android soft keyboard, is, animating up and down:

```
yourView.setWindowInsetsAnimationCallback(new WindowInsetsAnimation.Callback(WindowInsetsAnimation.Callback.DISPATCH_MODE_CONTINUE_ON_SUBTREE ) {
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public WindowInsets onProgress(@NonNull WindowInsets windowInsets, @NonNull List<WindowInsetsAnimation> list) {
        return windowInsets;
    }

    @Override
    public void onEnd(@NonNull WindowInsetsAnimation animation) {
        super.onEnd(animation);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public WindowInsetsAnimation.Bounds onStart(@NonNull WindowInsetsAnimation animation, @NonNull WindowInsetsAnimation.Bounds bounds) {
        boolean showingKeyboard = frame.getRootWindowInsets().isVisible(WindowInsets.Type.ime());
        if (showingKeyboard) {
            yourLayoutWhenSoftKeyboardShown();
        }
        else {
            yourLayoutWhenSoftKeyboardHidden();
        }
        return super.onStart(animation, bounds);
    }
});
```

You can then easily do any sort of animation you need, while, the operating system is animating the size of the window. Example,

```
Integer animDuration = 120;

private void layoutWhenSoftKeyboardShown() {
    ValueAnimator m1 = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(15f, 1f);
    m1.setDuration(animDuration);
    m1.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    m1.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            ((LinearLayout.LayoutParams) spacerOrWhatever.getLayoutParams()).weight =
               (float) animation.getAnimatedValue();
            spacerOrWhatever.requestLayout();
        }
    });
    m1.start();
}
```

This is all great but ...

#### How long is the animation?!

In iOS, the equivalent call that says "operating system is animating the keyboard appearance", it gives you as a parameter, how long the animation is going to be.

Then you just set your own animations to that value.

In Android, how do I get the length of the animation that is about to happen in `onStart` above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, figured it out:

`WindowInsetsAnimation.Callback` includes `getAnimationDuration()` .

Even better, because droid trumps ios, you can actually get the interpolator! `getInterpolator()` .

This means you can pass along the duration and even the interp to your own animations, wow!

```
@NonNull
@Override
public WindowInsetsAnimation.Bounds onStart(@NonNull WindowInsetsAnimation animation, @NonNull WindowInsetsAnimation.Bounds bounds) {
    boolean showingKeyboard = frame.getRootWindowInsets().isVisible(WindowInsets.Type.ime());
    if (showingKeyboard) {
        layoutWhenSoftKeyboardShown(
          animation.getDurationMillis(), animation.getInterpolator());
    }
    else {
        layoutWhenSoftKeyboardHidden(
          animation.getDurationMillis(), animation.getInterpolator());
    }
    return super.onStart(animation, bounds);
}
```

and then ...

```
private void layoutWhenSoftKeyboardShown(long animDuration, Interpolator animIpr) {
    Log.d("yoyo", "SHOWING");
    ValueAnimator m1 = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(15f, 3f);
    m1.setDuration(animDuration);
    m1.setInterpolator(animIpr);
    m1.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            ((LinearLayout.LayoutParams) whatever.getLayoutParams()).weight = (float) animation.getAnimatedValue();
            whatever.requestLayout();
        }
    });
    m1.start();
}
```

Beautiful!